# Multiple occurrences of diameter messages in a single TCP header

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tshark, diameter-protocol

I want to use tshark to filter and process diameter messages. In my capture, I see that I have three diameter messages inside one TCP header. My use case requires me to search for the Result-Code in the diameter message. According to the diameter specification, it is possible to have multiple result codes in a single diameter message. It is also possible to have no result code in a diameter message.

Because of this reason, if I get the result code as A,B,C for three diameter messages, I am unable to recognize which result code belongs to which diameter message.

Is it possible to apply some plugins/features that would help me to split the three diameter messages?

I could see that there is an old chain on a similar topic in https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/4291/multiple-occurrences-filter-for-diameter but there is no answer on how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your assumption regarding the Result-Code is wrong.

According to RFC 6733 (3588 say the same):

> 7.1.  Result-Code AVP
>
> The Result-Code AVP (AVP Code 268) is of type Unsigned32 and
>   indicates whether a particular request was completed successfully or
>   an error occurred.  All Diameter answer messages in IETF-defined
>   Diameter application specifications **MUST include one Result-Code AVP**.

If you will use wireshark you will be able to see each of the answers seperatly and you will be able to see easily which AVP belongs to each answer

Comment: First of all, I need to use tshark for processing the captures and not wireshark. This is because I have to analyze around 10Gb size of file.

Comment: More over, I agree that the spec mandates that there has to be a result code in each diameter message. It is also possible that a single diameter message contain multiple Result-Codes(One result code at the command level and others inside some grouped AVP). So if one of the diameter message that I am processing contains this pattern, then it would be difficult to map the Result-Code to the diameter session id.

Comment: If you have 3 answers and 3 result-codes I wouldnt worry about multiple result-codes.  Anyway when I want to split a big capture file I take the cap file to windows and use editcap.exe which is installed with wireshark (even though I never tried 10GB). You can find more data about it here: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html

Comment: @RajeevMenon  Do you need a tool that can split a tcp data packet into multiple smaller TCP data packet, each containing a separate response .

Comment: Yes. Something similar. By the spec, it is possible to have multiple diameter packets inside the TCP packet. I goal is to retrieve them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second Rajeev on this.  When analyzing large amounts of diameter messages, managing merged diameter messages in a single TCP payload becomes intractable.

Example:

```
tshark -Tfields -e diameter.Session-Id -e diameter.Result-Code -e diameter.CC-Total-Octets -r mydiametercap.pcap -Y "diameter.Result-Code" > session-ids-and-results.txt
```

This command will sometimes give me this (abstracted) output:

```
<session-id-1>,<session-id-2>,<session-id-3><tab><many result codes (sometimes 3 per message)><tab><one value of total octets>
```

I cannot trust that all the fields follow the same convention, and therefore cannot use a reliable parsing algorithm to review the results.  It's even worse when you think that the AVPs (that are interpreted in a very flat manner in this diameter implementation) could belong in an MSCC part or in a completely different part, and there is nothing to dissociate those.

Don't get me wrong: tshark rules... :-)  Just trying to make it better yet.

Comment: I found a way to work around this issue. It is lengthy but it works! Instead of converting it to text file, tshark provides the flexibility to convert to xml files. I am now using golang to process the xml.

Comment: And yes, tshark rules :)